# Skew only one side of before & after to get flat-arrow

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've created some dummy breadcrumb-steps.
The 1st breadcrumb-step need to have a normal flat border on the left, which is done.
And on hover, I need to show the black border for each breadcrumb item.

But the only problem is on hover, for the 1st breadcrumb-step, I don't get that flat border on the left as expected.

Here's what is expected on hover:

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.breadcrumbs {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 1rem;
 font-size: 0;
 margin: 1rem;
}

.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb-step {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 12.33%;
 height: 5rem;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black; 
}

.step-title {
 display: none;
}

.breadcrumb-step:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 transform: skew(30deg);
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-bottom: none;
 height: 50%;
 width: 100%;
}

.breadcrumb-step:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 transform: skew(-30deg);
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-top: none;
 height: 50%;
 width: 100%;
}

.breadcrumb-step:hover:before {
 border-color: black;
}

.breadcrumb-step:hover:after {
 border-color: black;
}

.breadcrumb-step:nth-child(1):before {
 transform: none;
 border-right: none;
}
.breadcrumb-step:nth-child(1):after {
 transform: none;
 border-right: none;
}

.breadcrumb-step:nth-child(1):hover:before {
 transform: skew(30deg);
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.breadcrumb-step:nth-child(1):hover:after {
 transform: skew(-30deg);
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
/*
.breadcrumb-step:nth-child(1) {
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.breadcrumb-step:nth-child(1):before {
 transform: none;
 border: none;
}

.breadcrumb-step:nth-child(1):after {
 transform: none;
 border: none;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
 <a class="breadcrumb-step" href="#"><span class="step-title">Home</span></a>
 <a class="breadcrumb-step" href="#"><span class="step-title">About</span></a>
 <a class="breadcrumb-step" href="#"><span class="step-title">Contact Us</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the transform-origin then hide the overflowing part of the skewed element and change the left border of the first child on hover:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.breadcrumbs {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb-step {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.33%;
  height: 5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
/*added this*/
.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb-step:first-child {
  width: 15.33%; 
  overflow:hidden;
  border-left:1px solid lightgrey;
}
/**/

.step-title {
  display: none;
}

.breadcrumb-step:before,
.breadcrumb-step:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;

}
.breadcrumb-step:before {
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transform-origin:right bottom; /*added this*/
  border-bottom: none;
}

.breadcrumb-step:after {
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  transform-origin:right top; /*added this*/
  border-top: none;
}

/*added this*/
.breadcrumb-step:hover:before,
.breadcrumb-step:hover:after,
.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb-step:first-child:hover{
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a class="breadcrumb-step" href="#"><span class="step-title">Home</span></a>
  <a class="breadcrumb-step" href="#"><span class="step-title">About</span></a>
  <a class="breadcrumb-step" href="#"><span class="step-title">Contact Us</span></a>
</div>
```